# PHP set an image on my server as uploaded temp file

Tags: php, image, file, imagemagick

I am editing a photo gallery script to allow the use of TIFF to be uploaded and saved, but i must keep the files in jpg format also for web viewing.
 What I have done is installed image magick to convert TIF to JPEG, once i have it converted I want the script to continue with making thumbnails, zoom images, etc. it makes them from
$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']

Is there a way to set my newly created file as $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']? my new jpeg file path is set to $nw.
    basically I need

```
    $nw='path/to/newfile.jpg';
$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']=$nw;
```

but it does not work. any ideas?

Comment: all of the code is pretty long, or i would post it. scrolls for a few pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to work on the same file across multiple page requests, move it somewhere safe using [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

If the functions that you wrote require access to `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`, rewrite them to accept the name of the file as a parameter and call them using the new location of the file as argument.

Comment: i was hoping to not have to but it seems there is no alternitive